Emulate platform for docker image only available for specific platform?
I have to test something with a specific Jenkins version. Sadly, the image is only available for linux/amd64.
As I'm working on an M2 MacBook, how can I test this without buying new hardware? Can I virtualize Docker somehow, so I can run the AMD image on my ARM machine?
I'm aware of buildx to build something for different architectures, but here I want to run an existing image on another architecture and I think that's not possible with buildx. Am I wrong?

https://corradoignoti.medium.com/how-to-virtualize-amd64-architecture-on-apple-m1-143f2773514c ?

Thought about this but hoped for something easier. Still it's an answer I could vote for if you put it in words underneath :)

There is a silver lightning Docker Desktop supports this on OSX using Rosetta!
First, you have to enable this in Docker Desktop -> Settings -> General:

Then you can run commands using export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 as a prefix.
The result is then images running in an emulated mode:

